# .htaccess - redirect if first folder does not exist

Tags: .htaccess

In my `.htaccess`-file the URL is rewritten. For example: `test.com/cat1/cat2/title.html` to `test.com/index.html?id=223`.

But I also want to redirect to the FTP-server via HTTP. For example: `test.com/upload/someFile.txt` to `http://ftp.test.com/www/someFile.txt`

This works: `RewriteRule ^upload/(.*)$ http://ftp.walderwerber.ch/www/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

But the problem is that I don't want to have the "upload"-param. It should be like this: `test.com/someUploadFolder/someFile.txt` to `http://ftp.test.com/www/someUploadFolder/someFile.txt`.

So I thought I can handle this if I redirect any folder to FTP which does not exist. But I don't know how because `test.com/cat1/cat2/title.html` also doesn't exist.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)$ http://ftp.test.com/www/$1/$2 [L,R]
```